# Android developers in Korean?

Tags: android

Im making this question because, i dont know if im the only one who happened this and how to fixed. In the last month i been acceding to the android.developers site without having any problem, but in the last 2 weeks, it started to show posts in korean, like this:
[image]

and it happens in all the site, showing me parts in korean and parts in english. I tryed to access to manually to the site, but it still resending me to the "ko" extension. I have the computer  in russian and i dont know if that influences the search. I didnt find anything related to this, and it starts to be really annoying. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this happen to me too! Clear your cookies and cached app data in settings. Google chrome: Ctrl-H, clear history, check only the above options. Close browser, re-open and check if it is still the same. This happened to me when I clicked on a Korean link to google dev page last week.

Comment: Thanks, so when you click to the korean version, it keeps resending you there everytime?

Comment: I think it caches that you have connected to the korean version, and every time you revisit the site, it sees that you have the korean version saved in the cache. Therefore, loads the korean version. I actually don't know the real reason, but I'm glad it fixed it for you :)

Answer (score 8):

At the bottom of the page you can simply choose the language you want and the menu will be in the right language again.

[image: Change menu language of Android developer]

Answer (score 2):

If it happens again: when you have the "intl/ko/" in URL -> just replace "ko" by "en".
IT works just right now (after months of research...)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than **clearing your complete browser data**,

> Right click -> Inspect Element -> Click on Resource Tab Now select
>   'Cookies' menu -> select developer.android.com  Here delete
>   'android_developer_pref_lang'

Now **close this Tab**. Open **develop.android.com** in **new tab**.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, from the javascript console (F12-Application-Console):

```
document.cookie = 'android_developer_pref_lang=en; path=/'
```

and then refresh the page